# What is the purpose of mixing brake cable housings?

Tags: brakes, cable-housing

Jagwire has in its offer Road Pro Brake Kit -- https://jagwire.com/products/diy-cable-kits/2017road-pro-brake-kit. The housing is two segments -- compressible next to the brake levers and for the rest -- compressionless.

Why mixing two types of housing? My only guess is that for road handlebar there is L-bend next to brake levers and here the forces from the cable are so big it is safer after all using "classic" housing (i.e. cable would not damage compressionless housing on the first day, but in time it could cut through -- this is my thinking).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the product linked, the short sections for near the levers aren't really classic compressible housing. Note the lack of a plastic coating in the last picture. They're more flexible for the bend in the bars and probably too compressible for the whole run. They also have built in end caps designed to mate with the usual housing

These short pieces can be reused a bit as they're well protected from dirt getting in, unlike a lot of rear cables.

Comment: Thank you, so your take is it is for added flexibility, not for more protection from the cable, right? One clarification -- the flexible segment has plastic coating, just unusual, it is simply transparent.

Comment: Yes, extra flexibility.  Mine didn't have plastic (on the outside) on the stock build; everything else matched that kit but it's possible there's a slightly different OEM version.  I've just ordered one because I had to fit compressible housing in an urgent repair recently, and would rather go back to compressionless before sorting out my bar tape.  So I'll see what turns up.

Answer (score 4):

I think they are using the more flexible, spiral brake housing next to the brake lever to allow for the tight bend on the inside of the handlebars.